# Mysqli count on php "Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array"

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, count

I want to do a simple value count with `mysqli`. I have

```
    $qnt = "SELECT COUNT(usu_nome) FROM esc_usuarios WHERE usu_indicador_codigo = '" . $_SESSION['codigo'] . "'";
    $qntresul = mysqli_query($conexao, $qnt);
    $colunaqnt = mysqli_fetch_array($qntresul);
```

But i'm receiving:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

I'm calling with `echo $qntresul['usu_nome']`
Thoughts?

Comment: try to user `fetch_row()`

Comment: Didn't worked, same error.

Comment: are you try this way  `$qntresul->fetch_row()` ?

Comment: It should be `echo $colunaqnt['usu_nome'];`

Comment: using $colunaqnt, it gives me "Undefined index: usu_nome"

Comment: yeah, i have tried that one

Comment: Oh that's because of the `COUNT`. Change `mysqli_fetch_array` to `mysqli_fetch_row` and use `echo $colunaqnt[0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this ,  will work fine   

 $qnt = "SELECT COUNT(usu_nome) as 'total' FROM esc_usuarios WHERE usu_indicador_codigo = '" . $_SESSION['codigo'] . "'";
            $qntresul = mysqli_query($conexao, $qnt);
            $colunaqnt = mysqli_fetch_array($qntresul);
    echo $colunaqnt['total'];
```